# Rspec should match is false but should eq is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

```
get :robots
response.should render_template("no_index")
response.body.should match "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"

Failure/Error: response.body.should match "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"
  expected "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n" to match "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"
# ./spec/controllers/robots_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

But

```
get :robots
response.should render_template("no_index")
response.body.should eq "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"
```

passes?

This seems relevant (irb):

```
1.9.2p318 :001 > "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n".match "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n"
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems likely highly *un*expected behavior to me, but I have figured out the issue. The Ruby documentation for String#match says

> Converts pattern to a Regexp (if it isn’t already one)

But this "conversion" seems to just mean changing "foo" to /foo/, without doing any escaping or anything. So, e.g.,

```
1.9.2p318 :014 > "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n".match /User-agent: \*\nDisallow: \/\n/
=> #<MatchData "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n">
```

If you use single-quotes but add in the escapes for the special regexp characters, the string matching also works:

```
1.9.2p318 :015 > "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n".match 'User-agent: \*\nDisallow: \/\n'
 => #<MatchData "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n">
```

However, if you use double quotes, it still doesn't work, because of the newlines:

```
1.9.2p318 :013 > "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n".match "User-agent: \*\nDisallow: \/\n"
=> nil
```

!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your string is being matched against itself (as a regex), which will more than likely fail due to the special characters like slash and asterix.

eq is indeed the correct matcher to use in your case.

http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000437

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but the match uses regular expression, where the `*` part means "any number of spaces", not "space-and-*". Escape that (or some other) character(s).

```
response.body.should eq 'User-agent: \*\nDisallow: /\n'
```